# How to Print list values

Tags: c#

I've got a program where I add different quotes to my List of quotes.
I add Quote to my list "Quotes" in my code, then i try to print "Quotes" and it prints
"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[GetQuotes.Quote]"
How do I get it to print the values I'm adding?

```
public static void LoadData()
{
    Quotes = new List<Quote>();
    Quotes.Add(new Quote(){
        HaulierName = "Hellmans",
        FulfillmentCenter = "BHX4",
        PalletQty = 2,
        Price = 122

    });
    Quotes.Add(new Quote(){
        HaulierName = "Pallet Online",
        FulfillmentCenter = "BHX4",
        PalletQty = 2,
        Price = 111.98
    });;
    Console.WriteLine(Quotes);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: When you use `Console.WriteLine(someObject);`, it simply calls `someObject.ToString()` which in this case, just prints the name of the object. Why? Because it has no way of knowing how you'd like to display the `Quotes` object (or even the `Quote` object) as a string. _You_ need to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need override `ToString()` method for `Quote` class.
Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8

You can do it in that way:

```
class Program {
    public class Quote {
        public string HaulierName { get; set; }
        public string FulfillmentCenter { get; set; }
        public int PalletQty { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return $"{HaulierName} {FulfillmentCenter} {PalletQty} {Price}";
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        {
            var Quotes = new List<Quote>();
            Quotes.Add(new Quote() {
                HaulierName = "Hellmans",
                FulfillmentCenter = "BHX4",
                PalletQty = 2,
                Price = 122

            });

            Quotes.Add(new Quote() {
                HaulierName = "Pallet Online",
                FulfillmentCenter = "BHX4",
                PalletQty = 2,
                Price = 111.98
            });

            foreach (var item in Quotes) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to have:

```
Console.WriteLine(Quotes);
```

You can implement own collection class and ovverride `ToString()` method inside.

Comment: It is better if you include code examples in your answer

Comment: @BasilKosovan Thank you, this has been very helpful for someone just starting like me, thanks!